# How to replace javascript alert with a jquery dialog box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to replace javascript alert (which pops up where the event called it) with a jquery dialog box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702730/how-to-replace-javascript-alert-which-pops-up-where-the-event-called-it-with-a)

Fellows, I'm going to break it down a little clearer. When I look at that JQuery UI stuff, I get absolutely confused as to what I need to download and where to put the files.

What I DID just do successfully was to link to the JQuery website so that I didn't have to download anything and saw that the dialog box works.

However, the dialog box, from the example shown me, is linked to a div. That div is not going to help me if it's at the top of the screen and the input box is at the bottom. I have only one function in the header that is called from a number of textboxes. This function includes a javascript alert() with a message.

PLEASE, tell me the EXACT code I need to type in the function that will pop up a message wherever the MyFunction is being envoked..

If it was javascript, in the head section in a script we'd have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function digitsOnly(){
alert("Digits only, please");
}

</script>
```

and in a number of textboxes, we'd have:

```
<input type="test/javascript" onkeydown="digitsOnly()" />
```

I need a beautiful pop-up box to replace the javascript alert(); I don't need this do do anything other than pop up a message next to the calling textbox. If it's draggable and resizable, that would be the coolest thing. But for now, I'll be happy with what I mentioned..

I study languages all the time. I know I'll eventually learn JQuery too. But I need this done tonight if possible.

James

Comment: Please edit your original question to clarify.  There's no need for a new question when you already had people trying to help you.

Comment: You have to 1.) Include jQuery 2.) jQuery UI 3.) jQuery UI CSS 4.) Make a div and call `.dialog()` like the example (http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Comment: I tried to delete the original question. The problem is I find people will answer and then I'd lose them. So editing the original, I was concerned, would be to no avail. No disrespect intended.. In regard to the div example u told me about, that's exactly what I'm afraid wont work for me. The div doesn't move across the page to where the calling textbox is, does it?

Answer (score 2):

Following is a very useful link for making a customized Dialog box:
http://www.queness.com/post/1696/create-a-beautiful-looking-custom-dialog-box-with-jquery-and-css3

You need to do the following:
1. Make a DIV element in the HTML body (as given in the link)
2. copy the CSS given into a CSS file and include it in your HTML
3. Include the JQuery's JS file using the following in HTML head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

1. Write the javasript given in the header section witin  tags.
2. OnClick of textbox call the method : popup("")

On any page where you want this dialog box, the js file having the javascript and the css file must be inluded, so make a seperate js and css file for reusability.

Comment: I like this Queness one because after reading it I was able to learn enough to create a fresh one from scratch and thereby can use it on commercial software without license issues.